# OSPF setup between EX2200 and EX4200

Tags: ospf, juniper, juniper-ex

Brief description: I have two juniper switches, an EX2200 and an EX4200. They are connected physically and OSPF is in the Full state, so they each see their neighbor, but they are not seeing the routes of their neighbors. In other words, the lsdb is empty of their neighbor's routes. Can anyone see any issue with my setup? I have a pc connected to the ex2200 as part of a vlan, so the route to the vlan l3 interface would be exported to the ex4200 if everything was done correctly, right?

```
Last changed: 2015-02-12 16:02:25 UTC
version 12.3R9.4;
system {
    host-name top;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$obtezp63$ymdQGDYSYDxbkqCV7Yf5t/"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    services {
        dhcp {
            traceoptions {
                file dhcp_logfile;
                level all;
                flag all;
            }
        }
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands any;
        }
    }
}
chassis {
    auto-image-upgrade;
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/4 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/5 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/6 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/8 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/9 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/10 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/11 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/12 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.0.2/24;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/13 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/14 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/15 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/16 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/17 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/18 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/19 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/20 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/21 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/22 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 12.0.0.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/23 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/25 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/26 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/27 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/28 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/29 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/30 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/31 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/32 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/33 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/34 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/35 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/36 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/37 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/38 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/39 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/40 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/41 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/42 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/43 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/44 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/45 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/46 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/47 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    me0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                dhcp {
                    vendor-id Juniper-ex2200-48p-4g;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vlan {
        unit 0;
        unit 111 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 222 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.2.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    router-id 10.0.0.2;
}
protocols {
    ospf {
        area 0.0.0.0 {
            interface ge-0/0/12.0 {
                authentication {
                    md5 1 key "$9$vUs8xd24Zk.5bs.5QFAtM8X"; ## SECRET-DATA
                }
            }
            interface ge-0/0/0.0;
        }
    }
    igmp-snooping {
        vlan all;
    }
    rstp;
    lldp {
        interface all;
    }
    lldp-med {
        interface all;
    }
}
ethernet-switching-options {
    storm-control {
        interface all;
    }
}
vlans {
    default {
        l3-interface vlan.0;
    }
    left {
        vlan-id 111;
        l3-interface vlan.111;
    }
    right {
        vlan-id 222;
        l3-interface vlan.222;
    }
}
poe {
    interface all;
}
Last changed: 2015-04-10 01:07:45 UTC
version 13.2X51-D35.3;
system {
    host-name bottom;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$dl.RvnLA$eJVUlArlIR1mau08boxqv0"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands any;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/4 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/5 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/6 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/8 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/9 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/10 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/11 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/12 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.0.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/13 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/14 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/15 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/16 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/17 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/18 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/19 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/20 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/21 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/22 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/23 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    xe-0/1/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    xe-0/1/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    xe-0/1/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/1/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    em1 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.145/24;
                address 10.0.19.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    em2 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.20.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    em3 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.21.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    vlan {
        unit 111 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.234/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    router-id 10.0.0.1;
}
protocols {
    ospf {
        area 0.0.0.0 {
            interface ge-0/0/12.0 {
                authentication {
                    md5 1 key "$9$bwY4ZHqfn/tUj/tuOcSwYg"; ## SECRET-DATA
                }
            }
        }
    }
    igmp-snooping {
        vlan all;
    }
    rstp;
    lldp {
        interface all;
    }
    lldp-med {
        interface all;
    }
}
ethernet-switching-options {
    storm-control {
        interface all;
    }
}
vlans {
    left {
        vlan-id 111;
        l3-interface vlan.111;
    }
    right {
        vlan-id 222;
    }
}
poe {
    interface all;
}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone, I just figured it out. No policies set!

Comment: Also, you can remove ge-0/0/0.0 from OSPF in your EX2200 - this is an L2 interface, so will not be advertised in OSPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any layer-3 interfaces in area 0 other than the link between the two switches, so you don't have any routes to exchange between them. You need to add the layer-3 interfaces you wish to advertise under the [ protocol ospf ] stanza, preferably as "passive" interface (so you can't inadvertently form adjacencies on those interfaces.

For example:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface vlan.111 passive
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface vlan.222 passive
```

Another possibility is to use an export policy to inject (all) directly connected routes:

```
set protocols ospf export export_direct
set policy-options policy-statement export_direct from protocol direct
set policy-options policy-statement export_direct then accept
```